# AndroidTV - customizing ListRow for X amount of rows. Focus lost

Tags: android, focus, android-tv, leanback

I'm using Leanback library in my Android TV project. I wanted to customize ListRow so I can change the amount of content lines I want to show (default is 1).

I followed guide: https://corochann.com/browsefragment-listrow-customization-android-tv-application-hands-on-tutorial-18-705.html

What I came up with is:

```
class CustomListRowPresenter : ListRowPresenter() {

override fun onBindRowViewHolder(holder: RowPresenter.ViewHolder, item: Any) {
    /* This two line codes changes the number of rows of ListRow */
    val numRows = (item as CustomListRow).numRows
    (holder as ListRowPresenter.ViewHolder).gridView.setNumRows(numRows)

    super.onBindRowViewHolder(holder, item)
}

override fun initializeRowViewHolder(holder: RowPresenter.ViewHolder) {
    super.initializeRowViewHolder(holder)

    /* Disable Shadow */
    shadowEnabled = false
}

companion object {
    private val TAG = CustomListRowPresenter::class.java.simpleName
}

}




class CustomListRow : ListRow {
var numRows = 1

constructor(header: HeaderItem, adapter: ObjectAdapter) : super(header, adapter) {}

constructor(id: Long, header: HeaderItem, adapter: ObjectAdapter) : super(id, header, adapter) {}

constructor(adapter: ObjectAdapter) : super(adapter) {}

companion object {

    private val TAG = CustomListRow::class.java.simpleName
}

}
```

And:

```
override onCreate() {
    val adapter = SparseArrayObjectAdapter(CustomListRowPresenter())
    setAdapter(adapter)
}

private fun setContent(content: List<Data>) {
    content.forEachIndexed { index, data ->
        val position = index.toLong()
        val headerItem = HeaderItem(position, data.title)
        val presenterSelector = getMediaObjectPresenterSelector()
        val dataAdapter = ArrayObjectAdapter(presenterSelector)
        val listRow = CustomListRow(position, headerItem, dataAdapter)
        data.content.forEach { x ->
            dataAdapter.add(x)
        }
        listRow.numRows = 5
        dataAdapters.add(dataAdapter)
        adapter.set(position.toInt(), listRow)
    }
    refresh()
}
```

So, everything is fine. I get the rows I wanted, but there's a problem. For instance, if I want to show 2 rows, it works perfect. If I want to show more than 2 (so you don't see second customListRow in a view) it doesn't have focus. Basically, if I have 2+ rows and I try to move left to right to bottom to top, focus works perfect on first 2 rows only. What could cause this and how to fix it?

Wanted output:

[image]

Data:

```
BIG-OBJ:
    title: "1"
    list-of-small-objs: small1, small2, small3
BIG-OBJ2:
    title: "2"
    list-of-small-objs: small1, small2, small3
...
```

Comment: So you want display multiple line content in your row-cell and for that to need to customize the cell Right??

Comment: I want to customize ListRow, but I do not think it's possible due to Leanback library limitations. Any other solution would be interesting as well.

Comment: Can you share the image about what exactly you want as output.. because I have made some changs in list and row-cell.. So may help you for that..

Comment: You just want BIG-OBJ(title 1) then some rows. Title2 again some multiple rows?? and with that focus should work perfectly?? correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes. Pretty much.

Comment: Then let me share you my code which is in java and is working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Please find my code in java.

Here **mainList** is containing header-name and list of data which will be added under specific header.

I my scenarios, I want 10 data in a row so with for **loop** of **j** I have managed that and multiple rows are added under same header.

```
for (int i = 0; i < mainList.size(); i++) {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> listDataMap = (ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>) mainList.get(i).get("dataList");

    if(!listDataMap.isEmpty()){
        CardPresenter cardPresenter = new CardPresenter();

        String categoryName = (String) mainList.get(i).get("categoryName");
        ArrayObjectAdapter listRowAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(cardPresenter);

        List<Movie> list = MovieList.setupGames(listDataMap,i+2);
        for (int j = 1; j <= listDataMap.size(); j++) {
            listRowAdapter.add(list.get(j-1));
            if (j%10 == 0){
                HeaderItem header = new HeaderItem( categoryName);
                mAdapter.add(new ListRow(header, listRowAdapter));
                categoryName = "";
                listRowAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(cardPresenter);
            }else if ( j ==  listDataMap.size() ){
                HeaderItem header = new HeaderItem( categoryName);
                mAdapter.add(new ListRow(header, listRowAdapter));
            }
        }
    }
}
```